# Create hooks in Python like WordPress?

Tags: python

Is there a way to create hook in Python that run function like WordPress (PHP) do_action(), apply_filters(), add_action() or add_filter()? Or is there a better Python way to do it?

I have found a good example on how to use observer pattern here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Science_Design_Patterns/Observer

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [Python signals](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) are what you're looking for. You could certainly implement the Observer pattern that way.

Edit: [Here's an example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20938/the-observer-design-pattern-in-python-in-a-more-pythonic-way-plus-unit-testing) of someone implementing the Observer pattern in Python using signals.

Comment: Christian, thanks for your answer. Any examples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of functionality is usually called Signals or Single dispatcher in the Python community.

Signals are widely used in modern Python projects/libraries to reduce coupling‎, but there's no implementation in the Python standard(the signal module can only catch some os signals, it is not designed for general usage). So different projects may implement their own signal system(e.g PyQt) or use a third-party signal/single dispatcher library(e.g Flask, Django). If you are using a Python framework, it is likely that the framework already had a signal system.

People today usually use  [PyDispatcher](http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/)(used by Django), or [Blinker](http://pythonhosted.org/blinker/)(used by Flask). They both have high code quality and good documentation. I prefer Blinker personally.

blinker example:

```
def subscriber(sender):
    print("Got a signal sent by %r" % sender)

ready = signal('ready')
ready.connect(subscriber)

class Processor:
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
   def go(self):
       ready = signal('ready')
       ready.send(self)
       print("Processing.")
       complete = signal('complete')
       complete.send(self)
   def __repr__(self):
       return '<Processor %s>' % self.name
processor_a = Processor('a')
processor_a.go()
```

Output:

```
Got a signal sent by <Processor a>
Processing.
```

Comment: I don't think it need a library. Example `change_me = apply_filter("my_hook", change_me )` and we hook to it `add_filter("my_hook", "function_to_call" )`. `apply_filter` will call all the functions that hook 'my_hook' and modify the a value.

Comment: @zourbuth Python don't have apply_filter and add_filter. You have to implement it. The implementation is not easy.

Comment: Yes I know, it was for example. Does that mean harder to create that than PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Decorators in python, the concept is similar to hooks and filters in WordPress but is more powerful.

You can read more about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/ [Decorators in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/)